# what is meany by Granularity in jmeter response time graph

Tags: jmeter

what is Granularity in jmeter[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0xBQ.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Granularity is basically the ["precision" of the chart](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/faq/what-is-the-granularity-of-my-graphs-am-i-seeing-raw-data-or-aggregates-on-my-graph/)

If you conduct a high load for several hours you will end up with millions of requests and it will not be possible to display all of them in the limited image of the JMeter's [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) so JMeter by default will aggregate the values with 1 minute frame but in that case you might want to increase the granularity to make graphs more "smooth"

On the other hand if the test lasts from several seconds to a couple of minutes (like in your case) you might want to decrease the granularity so the chart would take the whole width of the test duration time frame and you would be able to see lines, not dots.

The setting is controlled via [`jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration_general) which is defined in the *reportgenerator.properties* file (lives in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) and it defaults to `60000` milliseconds. The property can be changed in this file directly or in *user.properties* file or passed via [`-J` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override), check out [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/) for more information on [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html) and ways of setting and overriding them